# Multiplying a Rational Function by $-1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the following examples when dealing with the results of multiplying by $-1$ and substituting with $-x$:

$$f(x) = \frac{3x}{x^2-1}$$
$$f(-x) = \frac{-3x}{x^2-1}$$
$$-f(x) = -\left(\frac{3x}{x^2-1}\right)$$
$$-f(x) = \frac{-3x}{-x^2+1}$$

In the above examples, what am I  doing wrong with $-f(x)$>  The rule I am using is that a negative divided by a negative is a positive:
$$\frac{-}{-} = +$$
Should it be done like this?:
$$\frac{-}{+}= -$$
Additionally, if  I do it in reverse, do I get a different answer, or just a different form of the answer?  By reverse, I mean employing the following rule:
$$\frac{+}{-} = -$$

Comment: $-\dfrac ab=\dfrac{-a}b=\dfrac a{-b}$, $\quad-\dfrac ab\ne\dfrac{-a}{-b}$.

Comment: In fact, $\dfrac{-a}{-b}=\dfrac{(-1)}{(-1)}\cdot\dfrac ab=\dfrac ab$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are multiplying rational number by negative (aka. negating it) then you negate either only numerator or denominator,because if you negate both of them,then it cancels out and you did one step forward two steps back.

Answer (score 2):

When you multiply by $-1$(that negative sign before the quotient means that the quotient is multiplied by $-1$) you either multiply the numerator or the denominator. You don't do both as they'll cancel.

$$-\frac{x}{y}=\frac{-x}{y}=\frac{x}{-y}$$